# Is there any way to increase the stack size/recursion limit?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm writing a C program and am exceeding the recursion limit via a segmentation fault. Is there any way to increase the program's recursion limit (perhaps via increasing the stack size), either via an option to GCC or via a command-line option? The program is running on Ubunutu.

Comment: You mean you are overflowing the stack and hence a segmentation fault is happening?

Comment: @iharob: Yep, I verified this with `gdb`.

Comment: why don't you write it iteratively?

Comment: If you can convert tail-recursive call format can be replaced with a loop by optimizing the GCC.

Comment: The stack size for the thread created by the loader is a linker parameter, so yes.

Comment: You should not write very deep recursion function. It is not reliable and is a symptom of bad coding. Convert your program (e.g. using [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) transformation) to something iterative. Or make the stack frames smaller (by allocating most of the data, even temporary, in heap and `free`-ing it appropriately). Please edit your question to tell more about your C program, and give your recursive functions source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the stack size with `ulimit` on Linux, for example:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

On Windows with Visual Studio, use `/F` [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @iharob: The question is tagged gcc, if it were Windows it would probably be tagged mingw.

Comment: `ulimit -s unlimited` doesn't really make the stack size unlimited.  It just allows the maximum system configured limit to be used.

Comment: I think the OP wants to make bigger the 2M stack limit... you won't change that with ulimit, afaik that is another thing. (down made back)

Comment: @PeterHorvath what is this 2M limit you are talking about? And assuming this limit is 2M on Linux (it is usually higher) why would you not be allowed to change this limit on your system?

Comment: What ended up working better is giving it a number, e.g. `ulimit -s 1000000`

Comment: @PeterHorvath I don't know what you are talking about, static objects are not put in the stack.

Comment: @ouah Right. I wanted to say: using a local 3meg array. (NOT with malloc allocated, but simply a local char x[3<<10] or such).

Answer (score 2):

The stack size is a function of the operating system, though many earlier operating systems (MSDOS for example) didn't do program stack segment control:  it was up to the program to reserve an adequately sized segment.

With virtual memory and 32-bit APIs, the stack size is usually provided by a resource management mechanism.  For example, on Linux, the `ulimit` command provides one source of stack size control.  Other levels of control are provided by mechanisms inside the kernel enforcing system policy, memory limitations, and other limits.